# Why can't I find Chromium in the Finder and how can I delete it?

Tags: macos, chromium, finder

I have Chromium (not Google Chrome) on my Mac (on MacOS 11).
I want to delete it, but I don't know how because I can not find the application in the Finder and I can not find it when I look up `Chromium` in the Finder.

I'm not sure if this helps, but I don't remember ever installing Chromium in the first place (however, I do have another *Chromium based* browser).

How do I remove Chromium?

Comment: Do you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) projects, or do you use [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/)?  `node_modules` like [`puppeteer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) download Chromium (with the blue icon) when they are installed, although it's not to `/Applications` to my knowledge.

Comment: Yes, I have Node.js projects and npm.
So you are saying that installing any one of those automatically installs Chromium?

Comment: No.  I'm saying that, depending on which modules you have installed in each project, some of them may have `puppeteer` [as a dependency](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).  If so, you have Chromium.  However, I can't verify that this is even the reason you have Chromium, although I suspect it may be.  Try running `find . -type d -name puppeteer` in your home directory to see if it's installed anywhere.

Comment: Are you able to run Chromium?  If so, you can hold down the `command` key and click in Chromium's icon in the dock, which will show you exactly where it is.  It's a cool trick that applies to all items in the macOS dock :)

Comment: Wow, awesome! I'll write up an answer to make the info more visible.

Comment: Why did this get closed?  It's something that many may encounter it seems to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common reason to have `Chromium.app` installed on your macOS system is that a [commonly-used](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/network/dependents?package_id=UGFja2FnZS0xODEzMDc5NA%3D%3D) (GitHub reports 147,659 repositories are using it at the time of this writing)) `node_module` called [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) installed somewhere.

Even if you didn't install it yourself by running `npm install puppeteer`, it's likely a module used for one of your local projects or others' projects you're running locally, that depends on `puppeteer`.  It's essentially a headless (no-GUI) version of Chrome, so you can do all kinds of neat stuff like take screenshots of webpages and read/create/modify PDF documents, to name a few.

If you can open the application and get it to show up in your dock, you should be able to hold down the <kbd>command (⌘)</kbd> key and click on the app's icon in the dock, which will show you precisely where the app is located.